# Input manipulation before request validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I created request form validation in Laravel but when I want to add new input fields, it's not working. In my form, there are no inputs named town or city. I only wanted to add one in the Controller.

```
$request->all() // returns perfect with new inputs.

$request->validated() // returns without new inputs. because of that validation fails.
```

**ClientController.php**

```
public function update(ClientRequest $request, Client $client)
{
    $request->merge([
        'city' => explode('/', $request->post('citytown'))[0],
        'town' => explode('/', $request->post('citytown'))[1]
    ]);

    $validated = $request->validated();

    Client::whereId($client->id)->update($validated);

    return redirect('/clients')->with('success', 'success');
}
```

**ClientRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => "required|email|max:254|unique:clients,email,{$this->route()->client->id}",
        'fullname' => 'required|max:128',
        'idnumber' => "required|max:11|unique:clients,idnumber,{$this->route()->client->id}",
        'gender' => 'required|digits_between:1,2',
        'phone' => "required|max:10|unique:clients,phone,{$this->route()->client->id}",
        'adress' => 'required',
        'town' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `prepareForValidation()` method in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`.

```
$this->request->set(key, value);
```

Example:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->request->merge([
        'city' =>  explode('/', $this->request->get('citytown'))[0],
        'town' =>  explode('/', $this->request->get('citytown'))[1]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In prepareForValidation method, $request not working. I am not able to access request data.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You have access to request data via `$this->request->get(key)`.

Comment: simply use $this->get('key') if you are accessing request params in Request class

Comment: @sumit it is not that "easy", but works as a shorthand

Answer (score 0):

From the question I am assuming that

1. Your form doesn't have fields named `town` AND `city`, but you have field named `citytown` which is supposed to be filed by the user in format CityName/TownName
2. You intend to add these fields manually only in the controller code by splitting `citytown` field.

If this is the case you need to remove validation rules for `town` and `city` from your request file, after this you wouldn't get validation errors for these fields.
Also, you need to add proper validation rules for `citytown` field in `rules()` method of `ClientRequest` class.

So this is not a case of input manipulation before validation, just add validation rules for citytown field and split it in controller method.